Getting a list of "accounting earnings" adjustments
I'm reading Value: The Four Cornerstones of Corporate Finance. The appendix talks about the pitfalls of using standard PE ratios. In one paragraph it says Ben Graham would remove certain things from the numbers before calculating the PE value. Quote:

They adjust accounting earnings for a number of items, including nonrecurring profits or charges, the current position in the business cycle, capital structure, and so on. Using this data and information, they then estimate a sustainable level of earnings.

So where do I get the full list of items that are adjustable? Just to learn which part should be considered, as a reference.

Are you asking "how did Ben Graham adjust earnings?" or "how might an arbitrary investor adjust earnings?"  The latter is likely not answerable as there are too many idiosyncratic possibilities.

You can find this information in the financial statements, but how you use it is entirely up to you. The point is that the P/E (price/earnings) ratio can be manipulated somewhat by including one-time earnings into the total earnings or alternatively excluding some income from earnings, depending on the goal, or manipulating the price through capital reorganization.
Consider for example a company selling it's patent portfolio. This significantly increases the earnings for the year of the transaction, but is it going to happen next year as well? Probably not. So it's not sustainable. If you want to consider the company for a long term position, you'd probably consider removing this item from your considerations when it comes to the P/E ratios.
